# jQuery click event works only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-click-event

I've click event bind to a class called ".reportfile" as follow.

```
$('body').on('click','.reportfile',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    if(!$(this).hasClass('brc')) {
         // Perform some action here.
    }
});
```

Now I'm creating LI element dynamically with ".reportfile" class. Like this,

```
var inLi=$('<li>');
inLi.addClass('reportfile');
$(containerdiv).append(inLi);
```

Now when I try to click on the dynamic generated LI elements it only works on second click.

https://jsfiddle.net/mt7km8bz/

There is input box on the top of the UL to filter the list. This is where I'm creating new LI dynamically. LI element in filtered list has to be clicked twice to get it working.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? May be because you have certain condition in click handler..

Comment: Edited my question with jsFiddle link.

Comment: becoz the first click that get out of focus on search, then it clicked. that is your li does't recog first click..once the input value changed ,then it reacts the on click...

Comment: Try changing  `$('.ul1').find('.reportfile').each(function(index)` to  `$('.ul1').find('.reportfile').each(function(title)` and `var title` to `title`, finally, remove this as well `$('.ul2').html('');`. Is this what you want? Also according to css-tricks `e.stopPropagation();` is considered bad practice. https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3wzb4yqs/

Comment: @Raymond $('.ul2').html(''); Click event works by removing this line. But the filtered list doesn't get replaced with new data. I also need to ensure filtering function works properly.

Comment: @nisar changing "change paste keyup" to keypress function does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Alok, well, take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/x35qj3gm/

Comment: @nisar, Could got make out the reason of happening so ? Just `input` event is enough though..

Comment: @Rayon, Check my fiddle ....You should get it...becoz once the class  was created, It's enough to call $('body').on('click','.reportfile'.....

Comment: @snookieordie huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the focus on the input box, on first click input box still have the focus so the click event on list doesn't trigger.

So on the first click it losses focus on the input box and on second click event get triggered.

Changes to following worked for me.

```
$('body').on('keyup','.searchable',function(){
      // Some code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess jQuery click event works only after second click because the focus of the input.So I did a fool way that is trigger LostFocus Event using timer.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.searchable').blur();
},1500);
```

This is the code...
https://jsfiddle.net/2hkn2jpk/

Comment: Yeah, indeed! It has to do with input focus!

Answer (score 0):

change this to keypress , Its working.
   I cheked in fiddle.
   [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wzb4yqs/)

```
$( ".searchable" ).keypress(function(){
        $('.ul2').html('');
        var value=$(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
    if(value=="") {
        $('.ul1').show();
        $('.ul2').hide();
    } else {
        $('.ul1').hide();
        $('.ul2').show();
    }
    $('.ul1').find('.reportfile').each(function(index){
            var title=$(this).attr('title').toLowerCase();
        if(title.indexOf(value)>=0) {
                var LIin=$("<li>");
            LIin.addClass('reportfile');
            LIin.text(title);
            $('.ul2').append(LIin);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to add e as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
$(document).on('click','.reportfile',function(e){

    var id=$('.reportfile').attr('id');
    if(!$('.reportfile').hasClass('brc')) {
         // Perform some action here.
    }
});
```